# Why is my title and description have purple underline

Tags: html, css

This is the code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(makati2.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover; 
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.navbar{
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
   width: 12%;
   cursor: pointer;
}
nav{
   flex: 1px;
   text-align: right;
}
nav ul li{
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 60px;
}
nav ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 20px;
}
.row{
   display: flex;
   height: 88%;
   align-items: center;
}
.col{
   flex-basis: 50%; 
   text-decoration: none;
}
h1{
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 100px;

}
p{
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 11px;
   line-height: 15px;

}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
          <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
                 <li><a href="Req&con.html">Requirments & Contacts</li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>

     <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
          <h1>Car Rental</h1>
          <p>XP Car Rental is your go-to choice for cheap and affordable car 
          rentals in Metro Manila. Our well-maintained fleet offers a variety of 
          options to suit your needs, from compact cars to spacious SUVs. We 
          pride ourselves on transparent pricing, excellent customer service, 
          and convenient locations for easy pick-up and drop-off. Enjoy a 
          reliable and affordable rental experience with XP Car Rental.</p>
         </div> 
        <div class="col">

        </div>

     </div>

  </div>
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n79g.jpg)

I dont really badly know whats wrong with this

```
        <h1>Car Rental</h1>
        <p>XP Car Rental is your go-to choice for cheap and affordable car 
        rentals in Metro Manila. Our well-maintained fleet offers a variety of 
        options to suit your needs, from compact cars to spacious SUVs. We 
        pride ourselves on transparent pricing, excellent customer service, 
        and convenient locations for easy pick-up and drop-off. Enjoy a 
        reliable and affordable rental experience with XP Car Rental.</p>
```

I hope I can remove the purple underline. Thats the only problem I have, and also when I click the side of the description it also bring me to the other link please help me superrr duper, I am very much thankful about this. Thanks!

Comment: Typo.  You never closed your `<a>` elements, so pretty much the entire page is a link.  This is also a good opportunity for you to start using an HTML validator.  Whenever there's a problem like this, always start with valid markup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never closed your links (: The Anchor element) in nav bar.

Here's a fix:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Req&con.html">Requirments & Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```